# TensorFlow Operation and cannot be found in official API

Tags: python, tensorflow

recently I try to repeat and learn the code posted on GitHub by Nvidia--progressive_growing_of_gans. However, I find that there are several operations that I can not find reference based on official API as the following.

```
feed_dict = {}
setter = tf.assign(var, tf.placeholder(var.dtype, var.shape, 'new_value'),name='setter')
feed_dict[setter.op.inputs[1]] = value
```

What does the setter.op.inputs mean?

```
v = tf.cast(value_expr, tf.float32)
v.shape.ndims
```

What does the v.shape.ndims mean?

By the way, how can I get the reference for such class method? It seems that they are not included in official API.

Thank you, everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#shape) attribute of a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) object is a [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) object. As you can see in the documentation, [`ndims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#ndims) is the number of dimensions or "rank" of the tensor (or `None`, if the shape is fully dynamic).

The [`op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#op) attribute is the [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) that produces the tensor. In this, [`inputs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#inputs) is the list of tensors that are received by the operation. So:

```
feed_dict[setter.op.inputs[1]] = value
```

Means "take the operation that produces `setter` (the `tf.assign` operation), and from that take its first input (the `tf.placeholder` that is used as new variable value) and associate it with `value` in `feed_dict`".

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, how do you know these details about tensorflow? Are these included in the official documentation?

Comment: @Sean Well, mostly from experience really, I have had to use all these things at one point or another. The links I put in the answer refer to the official documentation (things like [DevDocs](https://devdocs.io) help, although it is currently stuck at TensorFlow v1.8), but many times I have had to go to the source code to figure something out.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Most of the time, I have to go to the source code to figure something out instead of the official documentation. Thank you so much!